# Why is SelectKBest is dropping a feature?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection

```
creditvals=credit.values
X_c = creditvals[:,:]
y_c = creditvals[:,-1]
X_train_c, X_test_c, y_train_c, y_test_c = train_test_split(X_c, y_c, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)
print('Train', X_train_c.shape, y_train_c.shape)
print('Test', X_test_c.shape, y_test_c.shape)

def select_features(X_train, y_train, X_test):
    fs = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k='all')
    fs.fit(X_train, y_train)
    X_train_fs = fs.transform(X_train)
    X_test_fs = fs.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_fs, X_test_fs, fs

X_train_fs, X_test_fs, fs = select_features(X_train_c, y_train_c, X_test_c)
# what are scores for the features
for i in range(len(fs.scores_)):
    print('Feature %d: %f' % (i, fs.scores_[i]))
# plot the scores
pyplot.bar([i for i in range(len(fs.scores_))], fs.scores_)
pyplot.show()
```

The issue lies in the output of the 3rd code block.
My dataset has 7 features, but I only get the scores for 6 of them. Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: There's an error in your code. If your last column contains the target variable, then your features should be `X_c = creditvals[:,:-1]` and not `X_c = creditvals[:,:]`

Comment: If you include your target in your features, you will get nan as score for that feature

Comment: @StupidWolf Thank you so much, truly appreciated :)

Comment: @StupidWolf I was wondering if you could help me out with this, I want to sort this based on the `total importance` attribute. The output of the list has been hosted here: http://dontpad.com/feature_importance